# How do I embed a YouTube video inside of a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, materialize

I am attempting to use the MaterializeCSS tooltip in oder to display a youtube video. I have set the html attribute in the jQuery to 'true' and added the embedded iframe code into the data-tooltip attribute in the HTML.

I am having issues with the quotes inside of the html iframe code, they are preventing the tags from closing. I tried escaping the quotes with the &quot syntax but all that did was display the html text instead of actually running the code inside of the tooltip. I've tried single quotes outisde with double quotes on the inside and that only shows a small thin blank box. I'm assuming that means the html is running but not displaying anything. Does anyone know what the problem is?

jQuery

```
$('.test-tooltip').tooltip({
            delay: 50,
            html: true,
        });
```

HTML

```
<a class="test-tooltip" data-tooltip="<iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Q8TXgCzxEnw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Because the HTML `title` attribute doesn't allow for anything but text content?

Comment: I think title is a part of the Bootstrap API correct? According to the Materialize docs I am supposed to put the html in the tooltip attribute in the jQuery but that does not seem to run.

Comment: Just use single quotes inside the parent double quotes.

Comment: When you move your mouse away from the the tooltip, the tooltip goes away as does the video. You'd be better off using the popovers for this effect. Using Tooltip in this way would be a bad UX for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div or element as the video container and add it to the popover as a return of a jQuery function.

jQuery:

```
 $('.test-tooltip').popover({
   delay: 50, 
    html : true,
    content: $('#youtube_container')
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<a class='test-tooltip' data-placement='top' title="Title" href='#'>Click</a>
<div id="youtube_container" style="display: none">
    <iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Q8TXgCzxEnw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

It should work.

Comment: This may be the right idea but the execution isn't quite right. The `display:none` needs to be toggled or something to work properly. When I remove the `display:none`, the youtube video appears on the page and when I click on "Click", the video will then appear within the tooltip. Just needs more tweaking to make it work. Again, I believe this is the right approach.